React Native android app crashes in release build when minifyEnabled is set to true
In my app level build.gradle file I have enabled minification
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}

Then app crashes when I install the apk in my android device.
When I checked the logcat from Android Studio, I get this error.
FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
Process: com.skoolbag.singleapp, PID: 7895
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke RNQBSettingsModule.init
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:192)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:147)
    at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

As suggested in similar questions I checked where RNQBSettingsModule is coming from.
What I found was this


Therefore, I added the following code to the android/app/proguard-rules.pro file to not obfuscate this particular package.
-keep class com.quickblox.reactnative.settings.** {*;}

But this this not resolve the issue

I fixed the crashes by updating the android/app/proguard-rules.pro file like given below.
To do that, I followed the readme file of quickblox-android-sdk.
https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/blob/master/README.md#customize-proguard-in-android-studio
The above steps are not documented in quickblox-react-native-sdk. So, I had to make minor changes to the match that.
# Adding minifyEnabled caused runtime crashes in the release build. To fix that I have added proguard rules relating to quickblox
# Refer to https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/blob/master/README.md#customize-proguard-in-android-studio

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ---------- 
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for quickblox  ----------

#quickblox auth module
-keep class com.quickblox.reactnative.auth.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.reactnative.auth.model.** { *; }

#quickblox users module
-keep class com.quickblox.reactnative.users.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.reactnative.users.model.** { *; }

#quickblox chat module
-keep class com.quickblox.reactnative.chat.parser.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.reactnative.chat.model.** { *; }
-keep class org.jivesoftware.** { *; }
-keep class org.jxmpp.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.jivesoftware.smackx.**

#quickblox videochat-webrtc module
-keep class org.webrtc.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for quickblox  ----------

##---------------End: proguard configuration ----------

